# Alt keys open window menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

Because of an accidental keyboard shortcut my alt key behave as the windows button. Button which does nothing now.
I cant use anymore the one, two, three buttons ... Cannot type At sign... It will just open windows menu...
Other things have changed too.
Sorry i cannot edit this text better because of all this mess.

This is for this kind of annoying things that nobody needs that I hate being back on windows already...

I desesperatly searched everywhere. Trying all kinds of key words on google, but founds.

Please i need your help do not close this topic...

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Profile (Account). Use Windows Account Settings to add a user. Log into the new Windows User and see if the new User works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug and replug keyboard was the solution

Comment: That sounds like a faulty keyboard or a faulty connection.